# How get users emails in though aggregation query

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

Parse doesn't return users emails in query response, I know what this is a preventive security measure in order to avoid data leaks, but I need get emails in aggregation query, how can I get it?
Can someone provide sample of code... I can't find needed info in docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse Server prevents sensitive information to be passed. If you are looking for a query that provides email information you'll need to use the masterkey.

```
new Parse.Query(Parse.User)
.find({useMasterKey: true});
```